# Error al actualizar laravel 5.5 a 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer, artisan

Muy buenos dias, en mis pasantias me toco trabajar con un proyecto en laravel 5.5 y al momento de actualizar la version me da este error, soy algo nuevo en laravel y no se muy bien a que se debe y/o como se soluciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

> [UnexpectedValueException] Unknown package has no name defined
> ([{"name":"laravel/installer","version":"v4.2.4","version_normalized":"4.2.4.0
> ","source"

Comment: En la imagen está difícil de leer. Por favor, copia y pega el mensaje como texto.